# Input common mode voltage of AC coupled differential pair

Tags: differential, common-mode

I was reading [OnSemi's AN8173 app note](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8173-D.PDF) and couldn't understand why input common mode voltage of AC coupled line is equal to VTERM.
My thought was each input of the receiver, D and \D, will swing between VTERM and VTERM-400mV, thus the common mode would be VTERM-200mV. Indeed, when I simulated the circuit with LTSpice, input of CML receiver, D and \D, initially swing between VTERM and VTERM-400mV and input common mode voltage is VTERM-200mV. However the common mode starts to drift to final value of VTERM, D and \D swinging between VTERM+200mV and VTERM-200mV.
Why is that so?

Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The receiver on-chip termination biases the inputs to VTERM, at the characteristic impedance of the line (50 ohms in this case.) The coupling capacitors block any DC path from the transmitter.

Without any signal, the inputs will be at VTERM. Apply a signal to the capacitor, and the capacitor will pass the AC part of the signal onto the input. The receiver-side signal will have a swing above and below VTERM.

What may be confusing you is the startup condition of the simulator leading to an unexpected bias. In normal operation the signal would be ‘DC-balanced’, that is, having an equal amount of time in each state on average. Then the AC-coupled bias midpoint is ensured to be very close to VTERM.

Answer (score 0):

Vterm is the only source of dc voltage to the right of the two series capacitors (C1 and C2) and they block dc currents hence the average common mode voltage at the inputs can only be Vterm.

Comment: yes, VTERM being the DC source to the right of ac coupling capacitors. So one side of my brain tells me input common mode has to be VTERM. However my other side of brain is telling me D and \D initially swing between VTERM and VTERM-400mV, thus the common mode starts with VTERM-200mV. Intuitively, what is causing the input common mode voltage to drift from VTERM-200mV to VTERM?

Comment: That’s what my answer tells you. The drift is due to the two capacitors charging their right side plates to Vterm. It takes a little while from an instantaneous start with everything previous at rest but after a while when the currents have settled down that’s what they become because that’s what capacitors do; they permit AC signalling to cross whilst leaving the dc conditions either side intact and different.